# NHibernate Merge is not checking for existing row before trying to insert?

Tags: .net, nhibernate

I'm writing an N-tier application that uses NHibernate and a Repository pattern to interface with a SQL store. Because the project is N-Tier, the NHibernate entities are mapped to the domain model who are then mapped to view models, and vice versa, causing models to be disconnected between NHB sessions.

The problem I have is that when I attempt to save a changed entity (an entity that has been recently instantiated to represent an old, changed entity from a previous session) using the Merge() method, I get an exception about violating a unique index on my table because NHB is trying to insert instead of update a row with the same ID as the entity. I've double checked my mappings, and that my entity contains all the right values in all the right places... it would seem NHB is not checking if a row exists before trying to insert, thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. The object graph causing this issue contained one-to-many relationships with the children objects referring back to their parents, and my mappers were instantiating new instances of the same "entities" for each child's reference to the parent. This meant that ChildA and ChildB's "Parent" property held instances that were not the same, but contained the same information, somehow causing NHB to want to insert new records instead of making decisions off the PK. I find this behavior odd because I am overriding Equals/GetHashCode to perform value-based equality but I'm just glad to have the issue resolved.